# Young kitten first day home, bathroom behavior

Tags: cats, behavior, toilet-training, feral

Today I just rescued a kitten that was under my porch at the restaurant I work at. One of my coworkers rescued him about two weeks ago, housed and feed him.

Because he is feral and has just been re-homed as well as visiting the vet all in one day, I was wondering if it was normal that he hasn’t went potty yet?

He has drank water and eaten some dry food I’ve given him (kitten specific dry food). He is around 6-8 weeks old. He is very shy, skittish and chirps for his mother. I’ve been wrapping him up in a little pillow case, snuggling and petting him. Once he settles in my arms, he purrs very loudly which I take as a good sign. I hope that he is just nervous and is getting used to a new environment especially after having such a hectic day.

I’m worried about him and hope that he is alright. Any help or tips are greatly welcomed! Thank you so much. Please note that this is my first cat/kitten.

Comment: How old did the vet say he was?

Answer (score 6):

A feral kitten will need some time to feel safe in a new home. It sounds like the kitten has started bonding to you and this is a good start.

As long as the kitten eats and drinks it will be fine, but it can take a little time before he dares to use the litterbox. To help the kitten, you can remove the lid from the litterbox and leave it off until he starts using the box.

A new cat/kitten will often use the litterbox only at night when the house is quiet. If the kitten does not use the litterbox very soon, you need to take him to your vet.

Answer (score 4):

Cats sometimes won't eliminate for an unusual length of time if they are under a lot of stress, especially in the situation of being introduced to a new home. However, not eliminating for too long can actually be harmful to the cat as it can be a sign of things like a urinary tract infection which in fact can even be lethal to a cat. Therefore, if the cat doesn't urinate over 24 hours, you should contact your vet. If the cat doesn't defecate over a few days, then it's also time to call your vet.